# Is this a bug on my adenium plant and what should I do?

Tags: pests, pest-control, bugs, pest-damage

I'm not sure what's going on with my adenium plant. But it's getting worst week by week.
It's on the balcony with direct sunlight from 11 to 16. I don't know if that stuff on the leaves is living things or not, but the bottom of the leaves is also full of black dots.
Any idea what should I do? Should I remove those leaves?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 2):

This is [scale](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale_insect), you can see them as the brown bumps.  They like to live where the flow of sap is the strongest along the mid line of the leaf.

I recommend using a Qtip or cotton swab soaked in 5 ml of dish soap to 1 liter of water and cleaning the leaves and stems.  Gently rinse after a few minutes as a thick soap solution can burn the leaves.

The key to successful control is to repeat the process every five to six days to catch the eggs as they hatch.  You will probably need to do this another three or four times.

Comment: With a limited plant size , scraping them off with a finger nail will also work .

Comment: @blacksmith37 sure, there is a risk that you will bruise leaf tissue but easy does it will do!